# IF Column has a value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write sql query to check whether the column y in a table x has a value. In python I can check that like

```
object.y = 1
if object.y:
   <statements>
```

Like this I need to check in Postgres

this is my query:

`request.cr.execute(""" select * from x where parent_id = %s and nav_include = true and website_published = true and cms_lang = NULL and y is TRUE order by sequence""",([event_root]))`

Here I need to check y has a value.

Comment: you can use coalesce function in the where clause

Comment: `and y is TRUE` is already checking if "y has a value". That condition will never return a row where y does not have a value ("is null").

Comment: yes The fact here is Y is not a boolean field, so I can't check IS TRUE @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Then use `y is not null`

Comment: yes you are right @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
request.cr.execute(""" select * from x where parent_id = %s and nav_include = true and website_published = true and cms_lang = NULL and coalesce(y, FALSE) is TRUE order by sequence""",([event_root]))
```

Comment: event_rel is an integer field @Vecchiasignora

Answer (score 0):

This is my solved answer

```
request.cr.execute(""" select * from x where parent_id = %s and nav_include = true and website_published = true and cms_lang is NULL and y is not null order by sequence""",([event_root]))
```

reference: https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/is_not_null.php

Comment: `cms_lang = NULL` will never return anything